# Problema do usuário possuia limitações e a resposta seria para outro assunto

Tags: debate

Bom, essa é minha primeira participação aqui, então qualquer coisa me passem algumas orientações, caso fuja muito do contexto (apesar de já ter lido os guias).

A dúvida é a seguinte, recentemente participei de uma pergunta, [Como usar grid com ng-repeat no angularjs?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/93733/como-usar-grid-com-ng-repeat-no-angularjs) onde após uma longa discussão tentando resolver o problema e entender corretamente o que ele desejava, percebi que a programação possuía algumas limitações e a solução só seria obtida através de modificações em outra linguagem de programação, em outra área. Neste caso, ao invés de ser um problema no AngularJs, a solução (não sendo a mais ideal) seria uma modificação na geração da array através do PHP.

A discussão acabou sendo movida para um chat, caso queiram ver, [este é o link](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31189/discussion-between-cesar-sousa-and-celsomtrindade).

Sei que ainda é cedo para tirar essa conclusão, mas durante o processo e conversa com o AP, ele pareceu se negar a aceitar a resposta pois não havia resolvido 100% a situação, mesmo fugindo totalmente do foco da pergunta.

O que podemos fazer? Ou como proceder nesse caso, ou em casos semelhantes que eu venha a presenciar no futuro?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Isso é inevitável

Infelizmente, não é incomum aparecerem perguntas cujo AP (Autor da Pergunta) não sabe exatamente qual o problema e depois se descobre que a solução está totalmente fora do escopo da pergunta.

Isso também é inevitável, já que sistemas são complexos e se o AP soubesse definir o problema perfeitamente as chances são de que ele também o resolveria sem precisar de ajuda.

## Ajude, mas voluntariamente

Muitas vezes alguns usuários, como neste caso, tem boa vontade o suficiente para tentar entender o problema e oferecer uma ajuda mais detalhada. Não há problema algum nisso e o chat criado a partir dos comentários tem justamente a finalidade de facilitar a resolução.

No entanto, é sempre bom lembrar que a participação no site é voluntária. Por exemplo, ninguém deve se sentir na obrigação de entrar num chat com o AP porque deu uma resposta que não refletia o real problema.

Não deixe o site perder a graça para você por enfrentar esses casos complicados.

## Pense no todo

Outro ponto importante é não esquecer que o objetivo do Stack Overflow não é somente resolver o problema do AP.

O maior benefício do site é atingir toda a comunidade de desenvolvedores, muitos dos quais podem se deparar com o mesmo problema futuramente.

Por causa disso, é muito importante solicitar ao AP que atualize a pergunta para descrever o problema de verdade.

Em casos como esse, vemos que a pergunta não descreve bem o problema, mas depois de alguma discussão chega-se a um consenso melhor do que realmente o AP precisava.

Não adianta ter essa informação numa sala de chat obscura cujo link está num comentário de uma resposta. Porém, se a pergunta for editada corretamente, todos poderão se beneficiar ou até responder melhor o que foi perguntado de forma que faça sentido.

## Cogite suspender

Em casos onde a pergunta, no estado em que se encontra, não pode ser respondida de forma clara e objetiva, você deve votar para a suspensão da mesma.

Neste caso em particular, duas opções de suspensão me vem à mente:

1. Não está clara o suficiente.
2. Fora de escopo > Esse problema não pode ser reproduzido.

Enfim, você pode votar para suspensão e educadamente deixar um comentário explicando para o AP como ele pode melhorar a pergunta.

Comment: Sim, a ideia não é prejudicar nem a pessoa nem a questão, pois sei que outra pessoa pode chegar ali e aquilo resolver o problema dela. Mas sim uma questão de organizar aquele tópico para que fique dentro do escopo. Fui um usuário bem ativo como 'questionador' no stackoverflow e aqui estou respondendo mais do que questionando, então sei muito mais dos benefícios de chegar aqui com dúvida e encontrar no lugar menos provável. Mas muito obrigado pela orientação!